# Regex, extract substring from a list of multiple options

Tags: regex, parsing

I am trying to extract out certain subtrings from email patterns.
I have a list of options the substring could match, is there a way to create a regex that will extract the substring from the total string if one of the matching substrings is in it. There is never be a situation where more than one substring shows up.

EX:

List of substring: confidental, customer, personal, unclassified.

- dgov-cpd-confidental@gmail.com
- dgov-rpt-personal-retr@gmail.com
- dgov-trp-unclassified-ret@gmail.com

In this case i want to extract confidential, personal then unclassified.

Comment: Is there a pattern/reasoning behing to extract exactly those words?

Comment: Yes there is a way, which language are you using? What have you tried?

Comment: You use alternatives in the regexp: `confidental|customer|personal|unclassified`